# SQL MAX: max date from multiple locations same part

Tags: sql, max

what I'm looking to find is that last or max date a part number was purchased from any store. so we can have so sales or sales and just give the max date:

| part | date | loc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 8/1/2022 | store 1 |
| 123 | 8/2/2022 | store 1 |
| 123 | null | store 2 |
| 123 | 8/3/2022 | store 3 |

result would be:

| part | date | Loc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 8/3/2022 | store 1 |
| 123 | 8/3/2022 | store 2 |
| 123 | 8/3/2022 | store 3 |

Comment: Not sure what this sentence is supposed to mean: *"so we can have so sales or sales and just give the max date:"*

Comment: At any rate, depending on your RDBMS, but supported by most: `SELECT DISTINCT * FROM (SELECT part, max(date) OVER (PARTITION BY part) as maxdate, loc FROM yourtable) dt` should do the job.

Comment: why do the results all have date `8/3/2022` as the result - I don't see any sales for that date for either stores 1 or 2

Comment: @ jnevilll "sales or sales" should have been sales or "no sales"

Comment: @topsail for my result i need the last sales date and i want to over write what the individual location did with what the company did.

Comment: `max(date) over (partition by part)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the max date in a subquery for every part, it would give you one  Result, the highest date.

The Query should work with most rdms

> ```
> SELECT DISTINCT [part], (SELECT MAX([date]) FROM Table1 WHERE part = t1.part) [Date],[loc] FROM Table1 t1
> ```
>
> ```
> part | Date     | loc    
> ---: | :------- | :------
>  123 | 8/3/2022 | store 1
>  123 | 8/3/2022 | store 2
>  123 | 8/3/2022 | store 3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=54ac585e575fdd78d3b8a6117186d2a7)*

Comment: you'd need to correlate the max per `part`

Comment: this doesn't seem to produce the result i was looking for. it jsut picks up the max from the date column and isn't per part. So for part 124 it is also giving the same date (8/3/2022) rather then the last sales date of part 124.

Comment: @JWIGHT i changed the answer, as suggested by Stu

Comment: @nbk Initially this worked but with further look it is giving me dates that ignore my Where. example: if my where is USEAST in getting dates from USWEST. do I need to add in locations in the subquery also?

Comment: that is not what you posted accept the answer as it answer your question and open a new one with the additional columns

Comment: what is your "where" that you are referring to here.

Comment: @topsail I didn't mention the where in my initial question because I didn't think that it mattered as table filtered properly.  But it is USEAST that I have as my Where. So with the answer above I need to add in the stores that I'm filtering twice. once in the sub query and then again in the main query otherwise i get sales dates from USWEST, USCENT,  USSOUTH.  It works so mark as complete.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure there is a more efficient way to do the query but I used a subquery. this should get you the desired result

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.[part], ad.x AS 'date', m.[loc]
FROM [MainTable] AS 'm'
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
  (SELECT MAX([date]) AS 'x', [part]
  FROM [MainTable]
  GROUP BY [part]) AS 'ad'
WHERE m.[part] = 123 --desired value
```

> [nbk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73338732/16806784)

There is the cleaner query.

Comment: this looks fine - although I am not familiar with the way you have used distinct here.

Comment: Actually, you are right, it's been a minute since I used SQL my use of distinct was incorrect. now fixed.